# Get Word bookmark index to replace image inside bookmark from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

This question is related with a [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607237/replace-image-inside-word-bookmark-from-excel).

I have an open Word document with a bunch of bookmarks, each with an inline image of an Excel table previously exported from Excel.

Now, I need to update the tables in the Word document as they have changed in Excel.

The way I'm doing this is matching the table names in Excel with the bookmark names in Word. If they are equal than I want to replace the existing images in Word by the current ones.

This is my code so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub substituir()
Dim Mark As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ShpRng As Range
Dim WordApp As Object
Dim DocumentoDestino As Object
Dim folha As Worksheet
Dim tabela As ListObject
Dim nomeTabela As String

Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
Set DocumentoDestino = WordApp.ActiveDocument

For Each folha In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If folha.Visible Then

    'loop all excel tables
    For Each tabela In folha.ListObjects
        tabela.Name = Replace(tabela.Name, " ", "")
        Mark = CStr(tabela.Name)

        With ActiveDocument
        If .Bookmarks.Exists(Mark) Then

            Set Rng = .Bookmarks(Mark).Range ' returns runtime error 13: Type mismatch, I guess it is because .Bookmarks expects the bookmark index instead of the name.


            If Rng.InlineShapes.Count Then
                Set ShpRng = Rng.InlineShapes(1).Range
                With ShpRng
                     Debug.Print .Start, .End
                    ShpRng.Delete

                End With
            End If
        End If
        End With

     Next tabela

    End If
Next folha

End Sub
```

The code seems ok, except for the line marked above that returns runtime error 13, is there any way to get to the bookmark index instead of the name or another way to fix the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from the `Range` object. There is such an object in Excel as well as in Word. Since you are running Excel, both Rng and ShpRng are declared as Excel ranges implicitly. Declare them as `Word.Range`.

Quite generally, be more careful with your use of variables. You perfectly declared `Set DocumentoDestino = WordApp.ActiveDocument`, but then you proceed with

```
With ActiveDocument
If .Bookmarks.Exists(Mark) Then
```

In Excel, there is no `ActiveDocument`. Perhaps that is why Excel correctly divines your intention to refer to `DocumentoDestino`. However, if you don't keep tight control instances are likely to arise - whenever you least expect them, of course - when Excel makes the wrong guess.

Comment: Thanks, my knowledge is limited to excel vba, and not as extense as yours. I have now improved the variables declarations, but the second if statement doesn't count any inline shape. Here's a link to the word document https://portalg-my.sharepoint.com/personal/nuno_portalg_onmicrosoft_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=177a32a1ed0a745bb93598158acd0f2ee&authkey=AWS7Irv4EdU6TL7gb8ewFgE

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't download your document, but thanks for the flowers. With regard to placing an InlineShape into a range you definitely have more experience than I, however. I added the count feature precisely because I had doubt about how to do that. Your shape must be next to the bookmark then. With Rng.Start and Rng.End you can define a range very exactly where you want it. The problem now is how, precisely, you add both bookmark and its InlineShape. Perhaps another question. Did you consider using the shape's caption?

Comment: Whittle down your choices. Shapes have names. InlineShapes have captions. Why have you discarded both options? InlineShapes have index numbers which are in the sequence in which they are loaded at the time of loading. Too unreliable? Create bookmarks for paragraphs where a knowable InlineShape will be the only one. Then find the shape within the bookmarked paragraph. Each solution has its own problems. You don't have to face all the problems for all the options. :-)

Comment: I tried using the inlinshape Alt text before, it works. But the problem then is how to replace one inlinehape by another?

Comment: Make it another question - with that title.